# Надо ли заносить composer.phar в .gitignore и почему?

Tags: git, composer

Собственно интересует вопрос, стоит ли привязывать composer.phar к проекту git? Если нет, то почему?

Встречал несколько проектов, где данный файл находится в .gitignore, но никто не cмог ответить почему.

Comment: Более общий вопрос: [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474556)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Игнорировать надо, потому что он а) весит мегабайт б) является не частью проекта, а внешним инструментом, ровно как и библиотеки, которые он подтягивает. Здесь хорошо различать два понятия - **билд** и **репозиторий**. Если первое - это уже законченный и готовый к развертыванию проект со всеми зависимостями (там, кстати, composer тоже уже не нужен - все зависимости уже должны стоять), то второе - это наоборот, легкий и переносимый проект, лишенный всех внешних зависимостей.

Comment: А как же тогда вагрант? По сути это тоже инструмент и не является частью проекта, но тем не менее его добавляют в гит.

Comment: игнорировать надо так как у многих он установлен глобально и в проекте излишен

Comment: @vladiik вагрант никто не добавляет в гит. переносимую конфигурацию - вагрантфайл - да.

Comment: а у него есть какой-нибудь конфигурационный файл, как `pom.xml` для Maven или вышеупомянутый вагрантфайл?

Comment: @NickVolynkin composer.json

Comment: @Etki: ок, буду знать. А зачем вообще `composer.phar` кладут в папку с проектом? Выглядит как-то странно, когда хранится по копии инструмента в каждом проекте.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно и в систему поставить. Просто в инструкции для развертывания все равно будет указан самый простой вариант.

Comment: @Etki это нормальная практика добавлять вагрант конфигурацию в гит проект

Comment: @vladiik а я что сказал?