# Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?

Tags: git, gitignore

Есть ли какие-либо общие закономерности о том, что в git-репозитории всегда нужно добавлять в `.gitignore` и что точно не стоит?

Навеяно этим вопросом: [Что должно быть в gitignore для Visual Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474392/181472)

Comment: Есть такой замечательный реп на гит хабе где вы можете посмотреть примеры .gitignore для практически любого языка ([клик](https://github.com/github/gitignore)) – AvtPhenix вчера

Answer (score 35):

## Как правило, нужно добавлять в .gitignore

1. Базы данных. Для них есть свои способы бэкапирования и применять для этого git нерационально или даже опасно.
2. Файлы, образующиеся в процессе и результате компиляции проекта. Как правило, для них отводятся папки с именами вроде `target/`, `output/`, `release/`, `debug/`. Эти файлы можно получить из исходного кода, поэтому их версионирование не имеет смысла.
3. Разные сторонние инструменты, которые вы положили в одну папку с проектом. А еще лучше просто не хранить их в той же папке.
4. Файлы, генерируемые тестовым фреймворком, профилировщиком, дебаггером и т.п.
5. Сгенерированная из кода документация — только если вы не генерируете ее в отдельный репозиторий, через который потом развертываете сайт с документацией.
6. Файлы, создаваемые при выполнении кода: журналы (`*.log`), результаты работы и т.п.
7. Временные файлы вашего текстового редактора или среды разработки. Часто их имя заканчивается тильдой: `*~`.
8. Файлы, создаваемые операционной системой, например `thumbs.db`, `.DS_Store`

## Стоит подумать

1. Большие бинарные файлы. Особенно если они постоянно обновляются вне зависимости от версии кода.

## Как правило, нельзя игнорировать, нужно сохранять

1. Все файлы конфигурации git игнорировать бессмысленно. Это сама папка `.git` (ее в любом случае нельзя добавить в индекс) и другие файлы: `.gitattributes`, `.gitignore`.
2. Файлы, которые определяют структуру проекта. Как правило, они создаются средой разработки. Их потеря в лучшем случае грозит вам потерями времени на перестройку проекта в IDE, в худшем — необходимостью вручную восстанавливать связи.
3. Собственно, код и сопутствующие ресурсы.

Comment: Вроде у джава-разработчиков принято файлы IDE убирать из гита?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если maven-based проект, то да. Там достаточно pom.xml и ещё, кажется, пары конфигов.

Comment: Весьма сомнительно, что 7 и 8 пункты надо добавлять в общий gitignore. Вещи, специфичные для конкретного редактора или ОС, надо прописывать в глобальный gitexcludes файл при первоначальной настройке Git.

Answer (score 22):

### В дополнение к ответу @Nick Volynkin

**Обязательно системные файлы ОС и бекапы**

```
### Linux template
*~
# KDE directory preferences
.directory
# MacOS
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
```

**Файлы самих IDE** (если вы работаете на локалке)

```
### NetBeans template
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
.nb-gradle/

### JetBrains template
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio
*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/
```

**Разные плагины**

```
## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
```

**Файловая система**

```
# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

**Дополнение**

*Из комментария @Timofey Bondarev*

Оказывается есть удобный сайт для генерации `.gitignore` – https://www.gitignore.io

Comment: Это из .gitignore для какого языка и среды нарезано? Похоже на IDEA.

Comment: Это более менее универсальный .gitignore. Все вместе это собранно плагином – `# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)`

Comment: ага, понятно тогда )

Comment: Тогда уж думаю, имеет смысл указать наличие сайта https://www.gitignore.io/ для быстрого создания более-менее подходящих файлов gitignore для различных технологий.

Comment: Наверное стоило бы написать, что игнорировать надо все файлы, начинающиеся с точки, исключение составляют (перечислить 2.5 файла).

Comment: @artoodetoo вообще нужно максимально все хранить в репозитории, даже .htaccess и разные конфиги. Какие файлы начинающиеся на точку вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @artoodetoo я делаю бэкапы папки  `~` гитом. Там половина файлов с точки начинается. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ниразу не сталкивался. Гит бекапы по умолчанию делает с постфиксом `~`

Comment: @korytoff, просто все те, которые в *NIX по идее скрытые, локальные настройки, .htpasswd и т.д. Когда есть исключение, тогда добавлять как исключение из правила.

Comment: @artoodetoo ну все от проекта зависит и от окружения. Я столько "разностей" видел на куче разных проектов

Answer (score 8):

А я вот сейчас влезу и выскажу непопулярное мнение.

Не смейте копипастить "стандартные" .gitignore. Вы должны понимать каждую строчку, иначе вы потонете в потоке WTF.

## Что НЕ надо добавлять в .gitignore репозитория

1. Мусор, генерируемый вашей операционной системой.

Всё это должно лежать в глобальном .gitignore, а не копипаститься в каждый репозиторий. Если ваша операционная система гадит в файловой системе, то разбирайтесь с этим на уровне системы, а не каждого репозитория, с которым работаете.

## Файлы, о которых надо ТРИЖДЫ подумать

1. Файлы IDE и всего к нему подключаемого. Вам нужно понимать, какие файлы и для чего нужны. Ради примера:

   1. R# + C#: `MySolution.sln.DotSettings` — "командные" настройки для проекта, `MySolution.sln.DotSettings.user` — "личные" настройки для проекта (есть ещё "системные", они в другом месте лежат). Нужно не только следить, чтобы заигнорен был правильный файл, но и чтобы изменённые настройки попадали в нужный файл, иначе с командой будут разногласия.
   2. IDEA: есть некислые мануалы по тому, какие файлы нужно хранить и зачем. Нельзя просто взять и заигнорить `.idea/`, потому что отвалятся настройки проекта. Нельзя просто взять и оставить `.idea/`, потому что ваши личные пути попадут ко всем и наплодят конфликтов. В других средах файлов может быть от нуля до бесконечности, готовьтесь изучить свой инструмент.
2. Генерируемые при сборке файлы. В разных языках и средах разные традиции, а вокруг отдельных файлов разгораются нешуточные споры. Ради примера:

   1. Composer + PHP: Хранить или не хранить `composer.lock` — зависит от приоритетов команды, библиотеку или приложение вы разрабатываете, и от личных вкусов. Вам нужно хорошо понимать, какие плюсы и минусы у нахождения файла в репозитории.
   2. T4 + C#: В C# принято хранить вывод кодогенерации, чтобы можно было легко собрать проект. При этом можно настроить сборку, чтобы кодогенерация запускалась при сборке, однако это возможно не для всех скриптов. Надо отметить, что кодогенерация не из T4 обычно попадает в Output, поэтому игнорируется. В других языках и средах чаще исповедуют идеологию, что вывод кодогенерации никогда не коммитится.
3. Бинарники. Git отвратительно работает с бинарниками, в отличие от "отсталых" VCS типа SVN. Репозиторий непомерно разрастается, если файлы часто обновлять.

   1. Если вы обновляете файлы редко, и они мелкие, то можно положить файлы на место.
   2. В противном случае лучше спрятать файлы в какое-нибудь другое место. Есть как универсальные костыли для Git (Git LFS), так и специфические для языка и среды инструменты (личный сервер NuGet).
   3. Если вы можете использовать NuGet, Composer, CPAN, Lein, Maven, то используйте. Бинарные зависимости должны быть там.

## Идеал

Вы должны стремиться к тому, чтобы в репозитории было **минимальное** возможное количество файлов, которых **достаточно** для сборки всего проекта абсолютно **без вмешательства** и настройки чего бы то ни было.

Часто идеал недостижим. Так что ищите компромисс.

Comment: Что такое глобальный gitignore? Это тот, который в корне проекта или ещё более глобальный?

Comment: @Mae Это который задаётся через `[core] excludesfile` в `.gitconfig`. На уровне пользователя.

Comment: Добавлю, что с таким подходом зачастую проще заигнорить всё, и unignore-ить только необходимые файлы.

Comment: @tocic Зависит от платформы. И платформы, и среды разработки могут иметь как зоопарк разнообразных файлов, так и однородное содержимое. Кроме того, при работе белым списком гораздо проще прозевать добавление нужного файла. При чёрном списке всё новое явно отобразится.

Comment: Наоборот, по-моему. Когда вы не добавили нужный файл в белый список, то вы пытаетесь закоммитить, а файлов для коммита нет, поэтому сразу замечаете ошибку. А когда у вас появляется новый игнорируемый файл, но вы забыли его добавить в чёрный список, есть вероятность его случайно закоммитить и не заметить этого. Если вы пытаетесь одним коммитом добавить много игнорируемых и неигнорируемых файлов одновременно, то тут уже зависит от того, чего больше. Но обычно стоит делать коммиты минимальными по размеру.

Comment: *Сразу замечаете*, т.к. при нехватке новых файлов ломается билд/проверки/тесты. *Есть вероятность не заметить*, т.к. при коммите игнорируемого файла обычно ничего не ломается.

Comment: @tocic Это *другие* замечают, когда не хватает файлов. А при локальной сборке очень просто не заметить, потому что у себя-то файлы есть.

Comment: С этим согласен. Можно запрещать пуш/мерж, если CI зафейлился. Также IDE от JetBrains, например, выводят предупреждения типа "You are editing file which is ignored".