# Нужно ли добавить файлы в .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Я сформировал файл `.gitignore` для андроид студии, указал в нем все как [написано тут](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) и положил его в корень проекта.

Я так понимаю, что должно покрыться все что не должно попадать в гит так как в файле перечислены почти все моменты.

Вообще как я понимаю, что в гит не должны вообще попадать файлы которые автоматически генерируются средой разработки...

Вот тут вопрос, когда я в терминале пишу `git status` то мне показывает файлы которые я не создавал следовательно они были сгенерированы, но почему они тогда не попадают под `gitignore` который писали люди которые знают, что нужно туда написать...

Нужно ли эти файлы отметить в `gitignore` или добавить их `git add .` ?

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin
modified:   .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
modified:   .idea/misc.xml
modified:   Application/Application.iml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-af.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-am.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ar.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-az-rAZ.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-az.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-b+sr+Latn.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-be-rBY.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-be.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-bg.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-bn-rBD.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-bn.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-bs-rBA.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-bs.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ca.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-cs.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-da.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-de.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-el.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-en-rAU.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-en-rCA.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-en-rGB.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-en-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-en-rSG.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-es-rES.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-es-rUS.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-es.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-et-rEE.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-et.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-eu-rES.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-eu.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-fa.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-fi.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-fr-rCA.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-fr.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-gl-rES.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-gl.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-gu-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-gu.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-h720dp-v13.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-he.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hi.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hr.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hu.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hy-rAM.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-hy.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-in.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-is-rIS.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-is.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-it.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-iw.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ja.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ka-rGE.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ka.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-kk-rKZ.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-kk.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-km-rKH.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-km.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-kn-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-kn.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ko.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ky-rKG.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ky.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-land.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-large-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ldltr-v21.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-lo-rLA.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-lo.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-lt.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-lv.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mk-rMK.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mk.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ml-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ml.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mn-rMN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mn.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mr-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-mr.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ms-rMY.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ms.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-my-rMM.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-my.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-nb.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ne-rNP.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ne.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-night-v8.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-nl.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pa-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pa.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pl.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-port.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pt-rBR.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pt-rPT.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-pt.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ro.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ru.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-si-rLK.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-si.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sk.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sl.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sq-rAL.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sq.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sr.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sv.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sw.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-sw600dp-v13.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ta-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ta.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-te-rIN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-te.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-th.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-tl.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-tr.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-uk.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ur-rPK.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-ur.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-uz-rUZ.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-uz.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v11.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v12.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v13.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v14.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v18.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v21.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v22.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-v23.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-vi.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-w820dp-v13.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-xlarge-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-zh-rCN.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-zh-rHK.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-zh-rTW.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values-zu.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/multi/values.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/anim-v21.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/anim.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/color-v11.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/color-v23.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/color.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-hdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-mdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-nodpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-tvdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-v21.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-v23.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-xhdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-xxhdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/drawable.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout-sw600dp-v13.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout-v17.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout-v21.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/layout.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/menu.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/raw.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/blame/res/debug/single/xml.json
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/instant-run/AndroidManifest.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$11.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$12.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$4.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$5.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$6.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/9.2.0/jars/classes.jar
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-classes/debug/instant-run-bootstrap.jar
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-runtime-classes/debug/instant-run.jar
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$11.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$12.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$4.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$5.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$6.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAssets/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugJniLibFolders/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugShaders/merger.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/classes.zip
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/manifest.crc
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/resources.zip
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug-androidTest.ap_
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/restart-dex/debug/build-info.xml
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/5/slice_1/classes.dex
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/5/slice_5/classes.dex
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$11.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$12.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$4.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$5.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$6.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/debug/folders/1/5/main/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$4.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$5.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper$6.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/CameraHelper.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass$2.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_1/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/UtilClass.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$11.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$12.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13$1.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$13.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity$3.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/folders/1/5/slice_5/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/activities/CameraActivity.class
modified:   Application/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/debug/jars/2/1f/main.jar
modified:   Application/build/outputs/apk/Application-debug-unaligned.apk
modified:   Application/build/outputs/apk/Application-debug.apk
modified:   Application/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
modified:   Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
modified:   Application/src/main/java/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.java
modified:   build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Кроме этих двух

> modified:   Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
>
> modified:   Application/src/main/java/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/tools/ImageSaver.java

Остальные не нужны файлы. Их можно добавить в .gitignore

---

Для сборки проекта точно нужны файлы с кодом, разметкой, ресурсами (картинки, строки etc). Также нужны gradle файлы, т.к. там зависимости и прочая нужная для сборки инфа указана. Также нужны файлы гит-а, типа .gitignore. Вроде, это всё. Без всего остального проект соберётся и ничего не потеряется.

Comment: Всмысле их нужно добавить в гит игнор?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, в игнор их) Правда, если они уже были закоммичены и запушены, то их придётся из удалённого репозитория удалять. Я так делал - удалил всё руками с удалённого репозитория, а потом клонировал репозиторий - больше эти файлы в коммиты не лезли.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду сделать команду `git rm --cached readme.txt` для каждого файла?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, я в консоль не умею) Возможно можно и так)

Comment: вы из `idea` как то удаляли? Может это быстрее...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, не... Я руками с GitHub-a удалял( Очень неудобно, так что лучше попробуйте чрез консоль)

Comment: А еще можно вопрос) А как вы понимаете какие файлы нужны, а какие нет?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну... Для сборки проекта точно нужны файлы с кодом, разметкой, ресурсами (картинки, строки etc). Также нужны gradle файлы, т.к. там зависимости и прочая нужная для сборки инфа указана. Также нужны файлы гит-а, типа .gitignore. Вроде, это всё. Без всего остального проект соберётся и ничего не потеряется.

Comment: gitignore поддерживает шаблоны с wildcard (*). Не перечисляйте все файлы.

Answer (score 2):

> Changes not staged for commit:
>
> (тут большой список modified файлов)

Это означает, что вы уже добавили все эти файлы в одном из предыдущих коммитов. Теперь недостаточно просто игнорировать их - нужно удалить их.

Минимальный пошаговый план:

1. Соберите себе .gitignore файл, используя шаблоны для Java/Android **и** своей среды разработки. В вашем случае это [Android + Gradle + IntelliJ](https://www.gitignore.io/api/android%2Cgradle%2Cintellij)

   - [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474556/181472)
   - https://www.gitignore.io/
2. Чтобы действительно перестать отслеживать все файлы, которые описаны в .gitignore:

   ```
   git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard | xargs git rm --cached
   ```
3. Коммит.

По-хорошему надо бы удалить эти файлы из истории коммитов, т.к. если они однажды были добавлены, то соответствующие им блобы будут храниться (и занимать место на диске) всегда.

Comment: Теперь разобрался) А можете еще обьяснить, что значит `действительно перестать отслеживать` я вот в руководстве по гит нашел команду `git rm --cashed file.txt` и если я правильно понял, то эта команда ставит на удаление файл из репазитория и перестает его отслеживать...